# How can i display a overlay popup window when page is loading

Tags: html, popup, window, overlay

i want to try to display a overlay popup window when my main page is finished with loading.

The secenario should be. A customer comes on my main page and a popup comes over and shows him a external page (event.php) in this popup. The background of this popup should be transparent.

Hope you could help me :(

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Where is your code? What is your question? Just asking "please do my work for me" is not exactly the questions meant to be posted here. This page is about getting answers to _specific programming issues_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout function(){
      PopUp();
   },5000); //5 seconds
});
```

Then for PopUp function you can use this plugin:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Hope this help.

Comment: many thanks for your solution, it helps me ! But now i have the problem. When someone join the main website and he gets the popup, how can i do it that he only see the popup once?

Comment: you can use cookies to store popupViewed state and then check this key before PopUp function call: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie